# Find the solutions of the equation...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

How can I solve this equation?

$$
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt[3]{x-2}+\sqrt{x-1}=5
\end{equation*}
$$

Frankly, I just have no idea at all!!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: One can find the root $10$ by "inspection." Then we need to prove there are no other (real) roots.

Comment: But what if I want to write in a more math-like way?

Comment: The left hand side is strictly increasing function. Equation has a unique solution.

Comment: Well, one can manipulate. To make things prettier we can let $y=x-1$ or $x-2$. Bring the square root to the other side, cube. Manipulate some more, you get an ugly polynomial. Then search for a rational root using the Rational Root Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By *cubing*, rearranging and *squaring* the given equation is reduced to a *cubic* equation. The original equation

\begin{equation*}
\sqrt[3]{x-2}+\sqrt{x-1}=5,\qquad u=x-2,\quad v=x-1
\end{equation*}

implies that

\begin{eqnarray*}
u^{1/3} &=&5-v^{1/2} \\
u &=&\left( 5-v^{1/2}\right) ^{3} \\
\left( u-125-15v\right) ^{2} &=&\left( -75v^{1/2}-v^{3/2}\right) ^{2} \\
&&\cdots  \\
x^{3}-49x^{2}+2192x-18\,020 &=&0 \\
\left( x-10\right) \left( x^{2}-39x+1802\right)  &=&0.
\end{eqnarray*}

You still need to *confirm* which solutions of this last cubic equation are solutions of the original equation, because in general the equation $A^n=B^n$ has all the solutions of the equation $A=B$ but *may have additional* ones.